# Count checked out files in sharepoint 2010 library using javascript

Tags: 2010, javascript, document-library, counter, item-checkedin

The checked out files can be reached via the UI by browsing Document library --> settings --> Manage Checked out Files.
I would like to do it using the usual "function, success, failed" procedure in Javascript. Here is the snippet to fill.

```
var oList;
function theFunction() {
    clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    web = clientContext.get_web();
    var oList = web.get_lists().getByTitle("MyLibrary");   
    clientContext.load(oList);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onSuccess, onFail);        
}
function onSuccess(sender, args) {
    //console.log(oList.Checkedoutfiles.count);
}
function onFail(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed.\n' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have to explicitly load the `checkOutType` (and `CheckedOutByUser`, if you want it)

```
    varwebSite = clientContext.get_web();  
    this.list = webSite.get_lists().getByTitle(listname);  
    this.folder = this.list.get_rootFolder();  
    this.files = this.folder.get_files();  
    clientContext.load(this.folder);  
    clientContext.load(this.files, 'Include(CheckOutType,Name,CheckedOutByUser)');
```

Try this, [from here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/54472d/populate-files-with-checked-out-status-using-jsom-in-sharepo/):

HTML

```
<!-- Style required for HTML Snippet -->  
< style type = "text/css" >  
.lst - table th  
{  
    background - color: #ddd;  
    border: 2 px solid# fff;  
    text - align: left  
}  
.lst - table td  
{  
    background - color: #eee;  
    border: 2 px solid# fff;  
}  
.web - heading  
{  
    padding: 2 px;  
} < /style>  
<!--Include jQuery library to perform dynamic html dom manipulation -->  
< script type = "text/javascript" src = "/siteassets/jquery.js" > < /script>     < div >  
< h2 class = "web-heading" > Files with checked - out Status < /h2> < div id = "fldrUrl" > < /div> < /div> < table width = "100%"  
    cellpadding = "10"  
    cellspacing = "2"  
    id = "lstTable"  
    class = "lst-table" >  
< thead >  
< tr >  
< th > File Name < /th> < th > Checked - out Status < /th> < th > Checked - out By < /th> < /tr> < /thead> < tbody > < /tbody> < /table>
```

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
functiongetcheckoutStatus(listname)  
{  
    varclientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();  
    if (clientContext != undefined && clientContext != null)   
    {  
        varwebSite = clientContext.get_web();  
        this.list = webSite.get_lists().getByTitle(listname);  
        this.folder = this.list.get_rootFolder();  
        this.files = this.folder.get_files();  
        clientContext.load(this.folder);  
        clientContext.load(this.files, 'Include(CheckOutType,Name,CheckedOutByUser)');  
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.OnLoadSuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, this.OnLoadFailed));  
    }  
}  

functionOnLoadSuccess(sender, args)  
{  
    varfilesEnumerator = this.files.getEnumerator();  
    $('#fldrUrl').html("Folder URL: " + _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + this.folder.get_serverRelativeUrl());  
    while (filesEnumerator.moveNext())  
    {  
        varcurrentFile = filesEnumerator.get_current();  
        vartrow = "";  
        trow += "<tr>";  
        trow += "<td>" + currentFile.get_name() + "</td>";  
        if (currentFile.get_checkOutType() < 2)   
        {  
            trow += "<td>" + currentFile.get_checkOutType() + " - Yes" + "</td>";  
            trow += "<td>" + currentFile.get_checkedOutByUser().get_title() + "</td>";  
        } else {  
            trow += "<td>" + currentFile.get_checkOutType() + " - No" + "</td>"  
            trow += "<td></td>";  
        }  
        trow += "</tr>";  
        //Append each list to the table as a row   
        $("#lstTabletbody").append(trow);  
    }  
}  

functionOnLoadFailed(sender, args)   
{  
    try   
    {  
        console.log('Error: ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());  
    } catch (err) {}  

}  
functioninjectMethod()  
{  
    getcheckoutStatus("Site Pages");  
}  
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(injectMethod, "sp.js");  
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I guess I can calculate the number of checked out files this way. However, I would like a solution that does not evolve browsing an entire library of 4000+ items to find out only 2 documents are checked out. This script is suppose to be run before my page is displayed. I'm afraid that it will take too long with a heavy library. Plus, my page already contains multiple calls toward the server before rendering. When trying to do the same with PowerShell there is a variable containing only the checked out files. I would like to get it using JavaScript too.

Comment: Your question does not reflect what you've commented here.

Comment: Then call the same endpoint Powershell probably does: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn450841.aspx

Comment: Yes I would like to, but as you can see all examples are using query that getting information about a specific file.